# Is a good practice to store UI logic in the database?

Tags: database

Recently I started working in this company and they showed to me this "framework" they use within the company for the project. And the main goal is to do everything from the database because that way it can be change later on without touching the code, only the database which is "easier". So it would look like the following:

```
|id |component_id |default  |read_only|visible|form_id|
|---|-------------|---------|---------|-------|-------|
|1  |2            |now() + 4|false    |true   |3      |
|2  |1            |null     |false    |true   |4      |
|3  |5            |null     |true     |true   |1      |
```

The `component_id` goes to a component table where they define each fields like date pickers, inputs, selects... And so on, and the `form_id` goes to another table where different forms in the app are, so like register, login, add_order... So on.

This is an over-simplification since they have more columns and more tables just to display the data in the UI with this, and have actions that trigger different thinks.

So my question is, is this a good practice? I mean, the code looks very complicated just to allow this and that database is a mess with a lot of different tables that only stores logic. Or is this use use something that people use very often, since I haven't encountered before.

We're using Dart/Flutter in the front end and I love the strong typed languages, but this removes the strong type for a guessing what value in the db is what we get and have a huge file with switch statements checking what component is to render it and apply all the other values.

I think is easier just write the code when needed since it simpler and better to look at instead of trying to figuring all this madness... Am I right?

Comment: You are right, it is horrific. Also could indicate that  people are constantly tinkering with data in prod, which is scary in itself.

Comment: Thank you, yeah. That's what I was thinking.

Answer (score 4):

This is a perfect example of over-engineering. There are numerous issues with this design. One of the main ones is the amount of risk that this introduces. Not only does it make development a nightmare, but it also allows developers to bypass any sort of risk-controls such as code scans. It also introduces a possible attack vector as it relies on an external mutable source for runtime behavior.

Data from your database should be just that, data. The business layer should be a stable set of logical instructions that manipulates that data. The less cross-over the better.

This kind of design also introduces problems with what amounts to versioning your dataset as you would your codebase. Then you have to make sure they sync up together.

Unfortunately, you probably have the original architect of this nightmare still around where you work, or your development team has gotten so used to such lax risk controls that a transition to a proper design will be like pulling teeth. If you are aiming to eventually push them in the right direction, your best bet would be to present the issues as a matter of risk versus reward and have a solution ready to propose.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sadly, I have to stick to this for now, since the developers are pushing it very heavily and the project is in a new/almost to prod  state were asking to change all of that would mean start all over and change it slowly would mean "losing" time. So I would just leave it as it is for now rising the issues and slowly refactor piece by piece, since all work with that "framework".

Comment: @MiguelBogota If this framework is not in production, I would make a heavy push to get rid of it before it gets entrenched in your company. That design is adding too much risk to justify the "reward" of easier updates.

Comment: Thank you! Then I'll do that and try to get rid of it.

Comment: @MiguelBogota: be careful. It’s hard to fight something like this, the creator will have significant credibility in the company and any criticism of the framework will be taken as an attack. It seems likely this was developed due to really bad or absent processes for testing and CICD, maybe an indirect approach where you advocate for improvements in those areas might improve matters. But it all depends on the political situation.

Comment: @NathanHughes Thank you, yes, I tried that over the week however is a slow process, like you mentioned I moving careful, I don't want to get fired just starting, and initially I'm stoping new functionalities to be added into this framework (since everything new is tried to be added in it), and then slowly refactor with the excuse of testing and CICD it would be better for everybody.